# WebAudio: cloning a source AudioNode

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

In order to support polyphonic mode, I need to clone source AudioNodes. That way I can assign a separate node to each note which will play together with other notes.

I want to do this in a generic way so that whatever source nodes are used, even custom ones, they can get cloned. I have checked the spec but found no reference to cloning nor copying of audio nodes.

Because these objects usually have native parts, I guess using standard JavaScript to clone the node objects will not work.

What do you recommend? Maybe this is a missing feature in the spec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that you'd have to manually copy the nodes you need. However, I think that's a pretty small job considering what you (probably) want to copy.

For instance, take an AudioBufferSourceNode. To copy one of these, all you'd really have to do is to create a new AudioBufferSourceNode and then assign the same buffer as the one you are copying. Since you're doing a polyphony I'm going to go ahead and guess that you want a different frequency and detune value on the new node anyway, so that probably shouldn't be copied. Additionally, if you're looping your buffers, you'd have to copy the looping properties (loop, loopStart, loopEnd).

Similarly, if you're dealing with an oscillator node as the source you probably only want to copy the oscillator type as, again, the frequency and detune most likely shouldn't be the same either.

So you see where I'm going with this - you should be able to whip up a small library of your own to copy the nodes you're interested in. I doubt that a native API method to copy a node would ever become a part of the spec (but that's just my personal guess, so if you think it's a good idea you can make a feature request at https://github.com/webaudio/web-audio-api/issues).

Comment: Thank you! Actually after some thinking I see that I would have to copy the whole graph, once per voice - so I will need to clone every node and their connections. And the problem is more philosophical: If there are more nodes in the future, my code would become obsolete, etc.

Comment: Don't see why you need to clone the whole graph.  Just connect the new cloned node to the same place as the original.

Comment: @RaymondToy I have envelope control (ADSR) which can influence not just audio sources but other effects such as the filter cutoff frequency. The envelope value depends on each noteOn/noteOff event, which is different for each voice, hence each filter node will have a different cutoff value depending on the voice.